# C# bit manipulation not working as expected

Tags: c#

I have a sample C# program given below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here

            byte prot = 1;
            byte media = 3;
            byte type = 7;
            var ProtoMediaType = (byte)(((int)proto << 6) | ((int)media << 6) | ((int)type));
            //m_ProtocolMediaType = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(m_ProtocolMediaType);

        }
    }
}
```

It is also available in Rextester [test code](http://rextester.com/NAU4609)

I am trying to assign value to a byte in the following manner

BIT 7   - proto
BIT 6:4 - media 
BIT 3:0 - type

In the code above I am shifting `proto` left by `6`. I am getting the result as `199`.

Even If I shift `proto` by `7` I am getting the same result.

Back of the envelope calculation shows that I should get `0xb7` (`183`)

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: The code you've provided won't compile. Please provide an actual [mcve].

Comment: But once the obvious flaws have been fixed, `(1 << 6) | (3 << 6) | (7)` is (in binary) `01000000 | 11000000 | 00000111` which is `11000111`, or 199 in decimal. Why would you expect anything else? Perhaps you should only be shifting `media` by 4 bits instead of 6?

Comment: (You should check how your "back of the envelope" calcuation works, because my guess is that it's not shifting `media` by 6 bits...)

Comment: @JonSkeet - you are right. I am shifting media by `4` which is what I should do in the code as well. and I should shift `proto` by 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 << 6 = 0x001000000

3 << 6 = 0x011000000

7 =    0x000000111

(OR) =   0x011000111 = 199

What's wrong?